# Which data type can be used for ISBNs - that only accepts 13 digits, including leading zeros

Tags: mysql, sql, char, varchar, isbn

I am trying to add a ISBN column to a table that requires the input to only be 13 digits. the number may start with 0. I have tried char, and varchar, but that hasn't worked. I need to make it so that it doesn't accept anything less or more than 13 digits long (e.g. '0123456789112'). What can I use to do that?

What I have tried:

- ISBN CHAR(13)
- ISBN VARCHAR(13)
- ISBN CHAR(13) ZEROFILL
- ISBN VARCHAR(13) ZEROFILL

Comment: MySQL does not have check constraints, so you would need to use a trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how would I make a trigger to do that?

Comment: Handle the constraint in your application logic (or your INSERT query)